# Adding horizontal space between fraction in mathjax latex code?

Tags: mathjax

Here is the equation written in mathjax

```
$$y=\frac{1 eV x^2}{2 md v^2}y$$
```

but it renders like this 
[image]

but i want to show like this

[image]

i know one idea like this

```
$$y=\frac{1}{2}\frac{ev}{2md}\frac{x^2}{v^2}$$
```

is there anyway i could write using only \frac one time? It would be better isn't it than writing \frac theree times and this may be just be example :)

thank you .

Comment: Three fractions need three `\frac` commands. How could TeX or MathJax split the fraction line otherwise?

Comment: @egreg it means i need to use frac three times ... but is it possible to accomplish using other like \over bla bla bla ?

Comment: Using `\over` is deprecated in LaTeX. You need three of them as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TeX and MathJax are not clairvoyant. If you tell them to typeset one fraction, they happily comply. But one fraction will have just one fraction line.

Your formula should be typeset as three separated fractions:

```
\frac{1}{2} \frac{eV}{md} \frac{x^{2}}{v^{2}}
```

or, maybe better,

```
\frac{1}{2} \, \frac{eV}{md} \, \frac{x^{2}}{v^{2}}
```

(spaces are optional, but make for good reading).

[image]

This is a MathJax rendering of the same:

[image]

but remember this is browser and machine dependent.

Using `{1\over 2}` is deprecated in LaTeX, so, unless you use Plain TeX for your documents, it's better to use `\frac` also in MathJax. There would be no advantage with it, because `\over` makes just one fraction line, just like `\frac`.

Comment: if over is depreciated then they should not have used it in no 8 


http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @user80946 - As @egreg has noted, the use of `\over` is deprecated in *LaTeX*. How people do their coding in plain-TeX or MathJax is a separate matter. Keep in mind that LaTeX and MathJax are completely different "under the hood".